# Scala debug this recursive example

Tags: scala, debugging

```
def append[T](xs: List[T], ys: List[T]): List[T] =
    println(xs)
    xs match {
        case List() => ys
        case x :: xs1 => x :: append(xs1, ys)
    }

append(List(1,2), List(3,4));
```

So the `println(xs)` code won't run.I basically want to see what hapepns when `xs1` is just a single element array. But how can I do this? I basically want to see if this is single element list is deconstructed into the single element and `xs1` is like `null` or `[]` on the next pass.

What debuggers does Scala have? How can I use them? Why doesn't `println(xs)` work?

Comment: Is it just a typo not to encapsulate the function in brackets? (`def append[T](xs: List[T], ys: List[T]): List[T] = { println(xs); xs match { case List() => ys; case x :: xs1 => x :: append(xs1, ys) } }`)

Comment: It should work. make sure append function is compiled first. use scala REPL which will help.